Change attribute value in selenium vba
I am trying to change the value of an attribute for an element using Selenium in VBA.
This is the url https://qic.online/en/visitors
The HTML of the element
<div class="input-container">
  <input type="text" class="input" placeholder=" " inputmode="numeric" data-maska-value="30/05/2024">
  <label class="label">Start date</label>
  <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="input__icon">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M17 2C17 1.44771 16.5523 1 16 1C15.4477 1 15 1.44771 15 2V3H9V2C9 1.44771 8.55228 1 8 1C7.44772 1 7 1.44771 7 2V3H5C3.34315 3 2 4.34315 2 6V10V20C2 21.6569 3.34315 23 5 23H19C20.6569 23 22 21.6569 22 20V10V6C22 4.34315 20.6569 3 19 3H17V2ZM20 9V6C20 5.44772 19.5523 5 19 5H17V6C17 6.55228 16.5523 7 16 7C15.4477 7 15 6.55228 15 6V5H9V6C9 6.55228 8.55228 7 8 7C7.44772 7 7 6.55228 7 6V5H5C4.44772 5 4 5.44772 4 6V9H20ZM4 11H20V20C20 20.5523 19.5523 21 19 21H5C4.44772 21 4 20.5523 4 20V11Z" fill="#394B5A" fill-opacity="0.8"></path>
  </svg>
</div>

I am trying the following but didn't work
Dim oElement As Selenium.WebElement
Set oElement = .FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='input-container']/input[@class='input']")
Debug.Print oElement.Attribute("data-maska-value")
.ExecuteScript "arguments[0].setAttribute('data-maska-value', '" & ws.Cells(iRow, "L").Value & "');", oElement

Any idea how to change the value of the attribute data-maska-value.
The code didn't throw any errors but nothing changed as expected.
To make it clearer, the element is datepicker and the outer html looks like that
<div data-v-db1db34d="" class="base-date-picker"><div class="dp__main dp__theme_light" data-test="BaseDatePicker"><div aria-label="Datepicker input" role="textbox" aria-multiline="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false"><!----><div class="dp__input_wrap"><div class="input-container"><input type="text" class="input" placeholder=" " inputmode="numeric" data-maska-value="30/05/2024"><label class="label">Start date</label><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="input__icon"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M17 2C17 1.44771 16.5523 1 16 1C15.4477 1 15 1.44771 15 2V3H9V2C9 1.44771 8.55228 1 8 1C7.44772 1 7 1.44771 7 2V3H5C3.34315 3 2 4.34315 2 6V10V20C2 21.6569 3.34315 23 5 23H19C20.6569 23 22 21.6569 22 20V10V6C22 4.34315 20.6569 3 19 3H17V2ZM20 9V6C20 5.44772 19.5523 5 19 5H17V6C17 6.55228 16.5523 7 16 7C15.4477 7 15 6.55228 15 6V5H9V6C9 6.55228 8.55228 7 8 7C7.44772 7 7 6.55228 7 6V5H5C4.44772 5 4 5.44772 4 6V9H20ZM4 11H20V20C20 20.5523 19.5523 21 19 21H5C4.44772 21 4 20.5523 4 20V11Z" fill="#394B5A" fill-opacity="0.8"></path></svg></div><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----></div></div><!----></div><!----></div>

I even tried to mimic and click on the element of the datepicker but with no good success
.ExecuteScript "arguments[0].click();", .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='__nuxt']/main/section/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/input")
I could manage the datepicker but need to select 4 months from the duration field
With bot
.Wait 1000
.ExecuteScript "window.location.reload(true);"
.Get sURL
.Wait 3000
Dim oElement As Selenium.WebElement
Set oElement = .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='__nuxt']/main/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/input")
Dim iDay As Long, iMonth As Long, iYear As Long
iDay = Day(ws.Cells(iRow, "L").Value)
iMonth = Month(ws.Cells(iRow, "L").Value)
iYear = Year(ws.Cells(iRow, "L").Value)
If Not oElement Is Nothing Then
oElement.Click
.Wait 500
oElement.Click
.FindElementsByXPath("//div[@class='dp__month_year_select']")(1).Click
Dim oMonths As Selenium.WebElements
Set oMonths = .FindElementsByXPath("//div[@class='dp__overlay_col']")
oMonths(8).Click
.FindElementsByXPath("//div[@class='dp__month_year_select']")(2).Click
Dim oYears As Selenium.WebElements
Set oYears = .FindElementsByXPath("//div[@class='dp__overlay_col']")
oYears(2).Click

.FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='dp__calendar_item' and div[contains(@class, 'dp__cell_inner') and text()='22']]").Click
oElement.Clear
End If
Dim oDuration As Selenium.WebElement
Set oDuration = .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='__nuxt']/main/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div")
If Not oDuration Is Nothing Then
.Wait 500
.ExecuteScript "arguments[0].click();", oDuration
.Wait 500
End If
'How to select 4 months for example

End With


What does "didn't work" mean? It didn't change the value? It threw an error? If an error was thrown, edit your question and add the full error message as text, properly formatted.

No errors but nothing changed.

Generally it's not a good idea to try to set values using JS. It goes around the UI that the devs have created, can create unexpected errors or behaviors, and in some instances just doesn't work, as you are seeing here. The better approach is to perform actions as a user would and interact with the UI

Thanks a lot. I even tried to mimic the user movements but I couldn't even click the element.

@JeffC I have updated the question and solved the first part
